# Training ff nn using backpropagation

Tags: c#, machine-learning, neural-network, backpropagation

I have encountered some difficulties while training my nn. When I use, lets say, 10 training sets, at the end of training procces neural network is trained just for the last two. I'm entering same values that I have used to train network and I am getting wrong results save for the last two. It seems to me that new nn memory suppresses older memory. I'm using 64 input neurons, 42 neurons in hidden layer and one output neuron. Sigmoid function is used for activating neurons. Training inputs and expected outputs are in 0 to 1 range. Does anyone have any clue what might be causing the problem?

```
    Neuron b = new Neuron();
    Fft f = new Fft();
    float e = 2.71828f;
    float eta = 0.05f;
    float alpha = 0.05f;
    float[] saw = new float[42];
    float[] dh = new float[42];
    float error = 0;
    float dto = 0;
    Random broj = new Random();
    TextReader br = new StreamReader("d:/trening.txt");
    TextReader ir = new StreamReader("d:\\input.txt");


    float NextFloat(Random rng, float min, float max)
    {
        return (float)(min + (rng.NextDouble() * (max - min)));
    }

    public void load()//load memory
    {
        int i, j;
        byte[] floatBytes;
        BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(File.Open("d:/memorija.txt", FileMode.Open));

        for (j = 0; j <= 41; j++)
        {
            for (i = 0; i <= 64; i++)
            {
                floatBytes = br.ReadBytes(4);
                b.w12[i][j] = BitConverter.ToSingle(floatBytes, 0);
            }
        }
        for (j = 0; j <= 1; j++)
        {
            for (i = 0; i <= 41; i++)
            {
                floatBytes = br.ReadBytes(4);
                b.w23[i][j] = BitConverter.ToSingle(floatBytes, 0);
            }
        }
        br.Close();
    }


    public void trening()//Get training inputs and expected outputs
    {                    //Calls process methode 
        int i, n,ct=0;
        using (TextReader tr = new StreamReader("d:/trening.txt"))
        {
            do
            {
                ct++;
            } while (tr.ReadLine() != null);
            tr.Close();
        }

        for (n = 0; n < (ct-1)/65; n++)
        {
            for (i = 1; i <= 65; i++)
                b.input[i] = Convert.ToSingle(br.ReadLine());

            process(b.input[65]);
            target.Text = ((b.input[65]).ToString());
        } 

    }
    public void process(double t)//Trains nn using backpropagation
    {
        error = 0;
        do
        {
            int i, j, k;
            BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(File.Open("d:\\memorija.txt", FileMode.Create));
            i = k = j = 0;
            for (j = 1; j <= 41; j++)
            {
                b.ulaz2[j] = b.w12[0][j];
                for (i = 1; i <= 64; i++)
                {
                    b.ulaz2[j] += b.input[i] * b.w12[i][j];
                } b.izlaz2[j] = (float)(1.0 / (1.0 + Math.Pow(e, -b.ulaz2[j])));
                if (b.izlaz2[j] < 0)
                    MessageBox.Show(b.izlaz2[j].ToString());
            }
            for (k = 1; k <= 1; k++)
            {
                b.ulaz3 = b.w23[0][k];
                for (j = 1; j <= 41; j++)
                {
                    b.ulaz3 += b.izlaz2[j] * b.w23[j][k];
                } b.izlaz = (float)(1.0 / (1.0 + Math.Pow(e, -b.ulaz3)));

                error += (float)(0.5 * (t - b.izlaz) * (t - b.izlaz));
                dto = (float)(t - b.izlaz) * b.izlaz * (1 - b.izlaz);
            }

            for (j = 1; j <= 41; j++)
            {
                saw[j] = 0;
                for (k = 1; k <= 1; k++)
                {
                    saw[j] += dto * b.izlaz2[j];
                } dh[j] = saw[j] * b.izlaz2[j] * (1 - b.izlaz2[j]);

            }
            for (j = 1; j <= 41; j++)
            {
                b.w12d[0][j] = eta * dh[j] + alpha * b.w12d[0][j];
                b.w12[0][j] += b.w12d[0][j];
                for (i = 1; i <= 64; i++)
                {
                    b.w12d[i][j] = eta * b.input[i] * dh[j] + alpha * b.w12d[i][j];
                    b.w12[i][j] += b.w12d[i][j];
                }
            }
            for (k = 1; k <= 1; k++)
            {
                b.w23d[0][k] = eta * dto + alpha * b.w23d[0][k];
                b.w23[0][k] += b.w23d[0][k];
                for (j = 1; j <= 41; j++)
                {
                    b.w23d[j][k] = eta * b.izlaz2[j] * dto + alpha * b.w23d[j][k];
                    b.w23[j][k] += b.w23d[j][k];
                }
            }
            for (j = 0; j <= 41; j++)
            {
                for (i = 0; i <= 64; i++)
                    bw.Write(b.w12[i][j]);
            }

            for (j = 0; j <= 1; j++)
            {
                for (i = 0; i <= 41; i++)
                    bw.Write(b.w23[i][j]);
            }
            bw.Close();
            izlazb.Text = Convert.ToString(b.izlaz);
            errorl.Text = Convert.ToString(Math.Abs(b.izlaz - b.input[64]));
        } while (Math.Abs(b.izlaz - t) > 0.03);
    }

    public void test()//This methode gets input values and gives output based on previous training
    {
        int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0;
        for (i = 1; i < 65; i++)
            b.input[i] = (float)Convert.ToDouble(ir.ReadLine());

        for (j = 1; j <= 41; j++)
        {
            b.ulaz2[j] = b.w12[0][j];
            for (i = 1; i <= 64; i++)
            {
                b.ulaz2[j] += b.input[i] * b.w12[i][j];
            } b.izlaz2[j] = (float)(1.0 / (1.0 + Math.Pow(e, -b.ulaz2[j])));
        }
        for (k = 1; k <= 1; k++)
        {
            b.ulaz3 = b.w23[0][k];
            for (j = 1; j <= 41; j++)
            {
                b.ulaz3 += b.izlaz2[j] * b.w23[j][k];
            } b.izlaz = (float)(1.0 / (1.0 + Math.Pow(e, -b.ulaz3)));
        } izlazb.Text = Convert.ToString(b.izlaz);
        target.Text = "/";
        errorl.Text = "/";
    }

    public void reset()//Resets memory
    {
        BinaryWriter fw = new BinaryWriter(File.Open("d:\\memorija.txt", FileMode.Create));
        int i = 0;
        int j = 0;
        Random broj = new Random();
        for (j = 0; j <= 41; j++)
        {
            for (i = 0; i <= 64; i++)
            {
                b.w12[i][j] = 0;
                b.w12[i][j] = 2 * (NextFloat(broj, -0.5f, 0.5f));
                fw.Write(b.w12[i][j]);
            }
        }
      for (j = 0; j <= 1; j++)
        {
            for (i = 0; i <= 41; i++)
            {
                b.w23[i][j] = 0;
                b.w23[i][j] = 2 * (NextFloat(broj, -0.5f, 0.5f));
                fw.Write(b.w23[i][j]);
            }
        }
        fw.Close();
    }

}
```

}

And neuron class

```
 public class Neuron
{
    public float[][] w12 = new float[65][];//(65, 42);
    public float[][] w12d = new float[65][];//(65, 42);
    public float[][] w23 = new float[42][];//(42,2);
    public float[][] w23d = new float[42][];//(42, 2);
    public float[] ulaz2 = new float[42];
    public float[] izlaz2 = new float[42];
    public float ulaz3;
    public float[] input =new float[66];
    public static float[] ioutput;
    public float izlaz;
    public void arrayInit()
    {
        int i, j;
        for (i = 0; i <=64; i++)
        {
            w12[i] = new float[42];
            w12d[i] = new float[42];
        }

        for (i = 0; i <42; i++)
        {
            w23[i] = new float[2];
            w23d[i] = new float[2];
        }
        for (j = 0; j < 42; j++)
            for (i = 0; i <=64; i++)
            {
                w12[i][j] = 0;
                w12d[i][j] = 0;
            }
        for (j = 0; j < 2; j++)
            for (i = 0; i < 42; i++)
            {
                w23[i][j] = 0;
                w23d[i][j] = 0;
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's impossible to tell what went wrong without seeing your code. Please post a **minimal** example that showcases the problem.

Comment: The code is crude because I used similar nn on my mC. I have modified code from c to c#. It has a lot room for optimization but right now I just need to get it running.

Comment: A training set consists of feature vectors x_0, ..., x_n and target vectors y_0, ..., y_n. You cannot train a normal feed forward neural network on more than one training set one after another. You have to make one training set, otherwise the ANN will forget the old training sets. This is known as "catastrophic forgetting". I did not read your code but I think what you mean is: "I have **a** training set with 10 **instances**. Is that right?

Comment: The idea is to get 64 voltage readings, scale them to fit 0 to 1 range and then perform fft to get fundamental frequency. So learning array will contain 64 voltage readings and 65th array element will be expected freq value that is also scaled. This represents one training set. When I perform fft on some other readings i will produce another training set. I then use first one to train nn until I get some small error value. After that I use second training set and so forth. I'm beginner to all this, is there some fundamental flaw in my learning process? What do you suggest I should do?

Comment: Training array, training set... Maybe I'm using wrong terms but I hope you understand what I was trying to say.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out what the problem was. I didn't mix training arrays, I was introducing one array to nn until it was trained for it, instead of introducing all arrays in cyclic manner. I hope this will be useful for someone.

Comment: Yes, that's a critical problem with backpropagation training. It is known as "catastrophic forgetting". You can read about that e. g. in this paper: http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download;jsessionid=DE0DFF02FCC641DA783DB32F76B60676?doi=10.1.1.36.3676&rep=rep1&type=pdf